# DOS game with medieval knight in hell

Tags: story-identification, horror

I played this game back in the mid 90's, in America, and I'm pretty sure it was for DOS.

Things I remember:

- You play as a knight in armor
- You start the game in hell on this platform at the bottom of a small pit, surrounded by lava
- You have a sword and a fireball spell
- It's first-person
- I think there was an orc or goblin on the cover art, and they were fighting a knight (probably the protagonist), and I think one of them had a spiked-flail-ball weapon thing
- Graphics were closer to *Duke Nukem 3D* than *Doom*
- Might've been a flaming skull enemy that shoots fire balls in the first room (the lava pit)

I never figured out the controls, so I didn't get far enough to be able to give more details.

Comment: Flaming skull that shoots fireballs? Doom, maybe? https://youtu.be/_slF2ne_drQ?t=54s

Comment: Shielder from Ghouls'n'Ghosts? https://youtu.be/xtiOmSQJC3A?t=8s

Comment: Catacomb Abyss? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09-cTU85uW8

Comment: @Valorum No, no, nope

Comment: Wouldn't [gaming.se] be a better place to ask this?

Comment: Arqade doesn't allow Game ID questions *without* a picture.  Quite the opposite of most other Stacks IME, but there you have it. :P

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - Nah. We'll get it. We just need a bit more info :-)

Comment: @Valorum I'm still thinking

Comment: Something about a spiked flail maybe?

Comment: There weren't a lot of wizard first person shooters in the mid-90s.  I would bet your thinking of catacomb abyss as Valorium says or [Eye of the Beholder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_the_Beholder_(video_game)).

Comment: Heretic or Hexen maybe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That sounds an awful lot like Witchaven or the sequel Witchaven II, both based on the Duke Nukem engine. Here's a screenshot from Witchaven II, complete with fireball and 'spiked-flail-ball weapon thing':

[image]

The covers don't quite match your description, but there's enough similarity that I'm proposing one of them as an answer.

Comment: Yes! It's the sequel! The orc I was thinking of on the cover is the second guy with the ax making the weird face. Quick find!